# Xcode4 and OpenGL - Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I'm making my first steps with OpenGL and Xcode4.
Therefore I created a new Project (*Application -> Command Line Tool -> C++*).

In the Project I go to *Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries* and add two frameworks: **OpenGL.framework and GLUT.framework**

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void RenderScene()
{
    glLoadIdentity (); 
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );  
    glColor4f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();
    glFlush();  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );                
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );        
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );        
    glutCreateWindow( "Name_1; Name_2" );   
    glutDisplayFunc( RenderScene );         
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the project the build succeed.

But at line `glutCreateWindow( "Name_1; Name_2" );` Xcode tells me "Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and it doesn't show up any window.

Please help me :) thanks!

**[[EDIT]]**

Here is the stacktrace:

```
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
    [Switching to process 7126 thread 0x0]
    2011-03-30 16:14:45.052 OpenGL[7126:903] NSSoftLinking - The function 'CGLSetOption' can't be found in the OpenGL framework.
    sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
    Current language:  auto; currently c++
    (gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fff815efb43 in createPixelFormat ()
#2  0x00007fff815efae9 in -[NSOpenGLPixelFormat initWithAttributes:] ()
#3  0x000000010001bad3 in createPixelFormat ()
#4  0x000000010001b251 in __glutDeterminePixelFormat ()
#5  0x000000010001b3f7 in __glutCreateWindow ()
#6  0x000000010001b7bd in glutCreateWindow ()
#7  0x0000000100000d2b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff6e8) at /Users/.../main.cpp:23
Current language:  auto; currently c++
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace from gdb.

Comment: BTW: I Added `glutMainLoop()` to the end and tried this under Linux and it worked (using freeglut), so it's fundamentally OK.

Comment: Sorry, but where can I find the stacktrace from gdb?

Comment: If you run your project from with Xcode it will appear in the 'console window' (I think it's called).  Press the button to show the bottom view.

Comment: I added the output above, hope this is what u mean :)

Comment: Ah that's it.  When it crashes type 'where' in that window and post the results here.

Comment: Oh nice to know that "where", added also above..thanks!

Comment: Could you try a different screen mode, by replacing the `glutInitDisplayMode()` call with `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH)`.

Comment: I tried your code on fedora 14, and it compiles fine.

Comment: @VJo: Agreed - see the 2nd comment - it also runs fine too!  This is almost certainly a bug in the Mac implementation of GLUT in `[NSOpenGLPixelFormat initWithAttributes]`.

Comment: @trojanfoe: tried with `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH)`. Still the same error :(

Comment: Not sure I can suggest much else.  Might be an installation-related issue as the code you have written is fine.

Comment: It is your project name. I had the same problem. What happens is the GLUT framework tries to look for the framework but your project comes up first, so the OpenGL is not properly referenced.

Answer (score 3):

I have got this code working on my Macbook Pro (home) and my Fedora 14 PC (work) using the code you have posted (with some minor changes - see below). Your problem would appear to be local to you, and not a problem with Glut or your code.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Slightly modified code (to clear the window and to enter the main loop):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void RenderScene()
{
    glLoadIdentity (); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );  
    glColor4f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();
    glFlush();  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );                
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );        
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );        
    glutCreateWindow( "Name_1; Name_2" );   
    glutDisplayFunc( RenderScene );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guess there is really a local problem on my MacBook. What IDE are you using on your Mac?

Comment: A Friend of mine has the same problem with this code. He also uses Xcode4 on MacBook..strange

Comment: There is a new knowledge... I named the project "OpenGL". When I create a new one with the name "MyOpenGL", everything works fine. Maybe you have a try to this?

Comment: No, I cannot see why using that name would break it, but if it's fixed, that'll do won't it :)